# How do I just create a parse tree with perl6 grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar, raku

I'm trying to create a grammar. Here's my code so far:

```
use Text::Table::Simple; # zef install Text::Table::Simple

my $desc = q:to"FIN";
record person
        name string;
        age  int;
end-record
FIN

grammar rec {
        token TOP { <ws>* 'record' \s+ <rec-name> <field-descriptors> <ws> 'end-record' <ws> }  
        token rec-name { \S+ }
        token field-descriptors { <field-descriptor>* }
        token field-descriptor { <ws>* <field-name> <ws>+ <field-type> <ws>* ';' }
        token field-name { \S+ }
        token field-type { <[a..z]>+ }
        token ws { <[\r\n\t\ ]> }
}


class recActions {
        method field-descriptors($/) { $/.make: $/; }
        method field-descriptor($/) { $/.make: $/; }
        method field-name($/) { $/.make: $/ }
        method field-type($/) { $/.make: $/ }
}

my $r = rec.parse($desc, :actions(recActions));
#say $r;

my $inp = q:to"FIN";
adam    26
joe     23
mark    51
FIN

sub splitter($line) { 
        my @lst = split /\s+/, $line; 
}


sub matrixify(&splitter, $data)
{
        my @d = (split /\n/, (trim-trailing $data)).map( -> $x { splitter $x ; } );
        #@d.say;
        #my @cols = <name age>;
        #say lol2table(@cols, @d).join("\n");
        @d;
}

#my @cols =<A B>;
#my @rows = ([1,2], [3,4]);
#say lol2table(@cols, @rows).join("\n");

my @m = matrixify &splitter, $inp;

sub tabulate($rec-desc, @matrix)
{
        my $fds = $rec-desc<field-descriptors>;
        #say %fds<field-name>;
        say $fds;
        my @cols = $rec-desc.<field-descriptors>.map( -> $fd { say $fd; $fd.<field-name> ; 1;} );
        #say $rec-desc.<field-descriptors>;
        #say @cols;
}
tabulate $r, @m ;
```

I really just want the grammar to create a tree of lists/hash tables from the input. The output from the code is:

```
｢
    name string;
    age  int;｣
 field-descriptor => ｢
    name string;｣
  ws => ｢
｣
  ws => ｢   ｣
  field-name => ｢name｣
  ws => ｢ ｣
  field-type => ｢string｣
 field-descriptor => ｢
    age  int;｣
  ws => ｢
｣
  ws => ｢   ｣
  field-name => ｢age｣
  ws => ｢ ｣
  ws => ｢ ｣
  field-type => ｢int｣
```

which looks fairly good. perl6 seems to be decoding the fact that `field-descriptors` is composed of multiple `field-descriptor`, but it doesn't actually seem to put them into a list. I can do `say $fds;`, but I can't do `say $fds[0];`. Why does the former "work", but the latter doesn't?

I must admit to having a fairly weak grasp of what's going on. Would I be better of using rules instead of tokens? Do I really need an actions class; can't I just get perl to "automagically" populate the parse tree for me without having to specify a class of actions?

**Update**: possible solution

Suppose we just want to parse:

```
my $desc = q:to"FIN";
record person
    name string;
    age  int;
end-record
FIN
```

and report on the field names and types that we find. I'm going to make a slight simplification to the grammar I wrote above:

```
grammar rec {
    token TOP { <ws>* 'record' \s+ <rec-name> <field-descriptor>+ <ws> 'end-record' <ws> }  
    token rec-name { \S+ }
    token field-descriptor { <ws>* <field-name> <ws>+ <field-type> <ws>* ';' }
    token field-name { \S+ }
    token field-type { <[a..z]>+ }
    token ws { <[\r\n\t\ ]> }
}
```

Let's eschew actions completely, and just parse it into a tree:

```
my $r1 = rec.parse($desc);
```

Let's now inspect our handiwork, and print out the name and type for each field that we have parsed:

```
for $r1<field-descriptor> -> $fd { say "Name: $fd<field-name>, Type: $fd<field-type>"; }
```

Our output is as we expect:

```
Name: name, Type: string
Name: age, Type: int
```

Comment: I notice that the following does work, though: `$fds<field-descriptors><field-descriptor>[0]` So I think I must be getting closer.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/40799024/1077672 help?

Comment: `$/.make: $/` is effectively a no-op. Also you need to call `.made` or `.ast` on the result of `.parse` to get at the result of the actions class.

Comment: Hi @blippy Have you figured out what you need to know?

Comment: @ralpha Yes thanks. I think I've got it figured. I also now understand what the deal is with `make` and `made`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you're now all set but here's an answer to wrap things up for others reading things later.

> How do I just create a parse tree with perl6 grammar?

It's as simple as it can get: just use the return value from calling one of the built in parsing routines.

(Provided parsing is successful `parse` and cousins return a [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree).)

> The output from the code ... looks fairly good. perl6 seems to be decoding the fact that field-descriptors is composed of multiple field-descriptor, but it doesn't actually seem to put them into a list. I can do say $fds;, but I can't do say $fds[0];. Why does the former "work", but the latter doesn't?

See my answer to the SO question ["How do I access the captures within a match?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779935/how-do-i-access-the-captures-within-a-match).

> Would I be better of using rules instead of tokens?

The only difference between a token and a rule is the default for interpreting bare whitespace that you include within the token/rule.

(Bare whitespace within a *token* is completely ignored. Bare whitespace within a *rule* denotes "there can be whitespace at this point in the input".)

> Do I really need an actions class[?]

No.

Only bother with an actions class if you want to systematically post process the parse tree.

> can't I just get perl to "automagically" populate the parse tree for me without having to specify a class of actions?

Yes. Any time you call `parse` and the parse is successful its return value is a parse tree.

> **Update:** possible solution
>
> Let's eschew actions completely, and just parse it into a tree:

Right. If all you want is the parse tree then you don't need an actions class and you don't need to call `make` or `made`.

Conversely, if you want another tree, such as an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), then you will probably find it convenient to use the built in `make` and `made` routines. And if you use `make` and `made` you may well find it appropriate to use them in conjunction with a separate actions class rather than just embedding them directly in the grammar's rules/tokens/regexes.