# list return from Inline::Perl5 gives a count of items, not the list

Tags: perl, raku

Some simple Inline::Perl5 code returns a list, but it seems to return the count of the items rather than the actual list.

Changing the number of items involved changes the count.

```
use Inline::Perl5;                                             
my $p5 = Inline::Perl5.new;                                    
                                                               
my $perl5_code = q:to/END/;                                    
   sub p5_data {                                               
      my @monsters = qw( godzilla blob tingler kong dorisday );
      return @monsters;                                        
   }                                                           
                                                               
   p5_data();                                                  
END                                                            
                                                               
my @stuff = $p5.run: $perl5_code;                              
say @stuff; # [5]
```

I thought I'd get the list of strings stored in the array, but instead it acts like something is switching it to scalar context.

**Update:**

ikeami points out that it works better to return the reference to
the array:

```
return \@monsters;
```

Though, then you end up with an array in the first element of the
@stuff array when you do this:

```
my @stuff = $p5.run: $perl5_code;
```

An alternate approach (from reading the Inline::Perl5 docs), is after doing a `$p5.run` to define the perl5 sub, to call it from perl6:

```
my @stuff = $p5.call('p5_data');
```

Then the list return (`return @monsters;`) gets loaded into the
array as I expected:

```
[godzilla blob tingler kong dorisday]
```

This is a recently installed Inline::Perl5 of version 0.40, on
"Rakudo Star version 2019.03.1 built on MoarVM version 2019.03 implementing
Perl 6.d".

**Update2:**  So, it seems that "run" implies a scalar context and "call" is a list context.

```
use Inline::Perl5;
my $p5 = Inline::Perl5.new;

my $perl5_defsub = q:to/END/;
   sub whadaya_want {
       wantarray() ? 'LIST' : 'SCALAR';
   }
END

$p5.run: $perl5_defsub;

my $run_context  = $p5.run(  'whadaya_want' );
my $call_context = $p5.call( 'whadaya_want' );  

say "run: ", $run_context;
say "call: ", $call_context;
# run: SCALAR
# call: LIST
```

Comment: Does using `return \@monsters;` help?

Comment: `return \@monsters` works  for me

Comment: ikegami: yes, returning the reference to \@monsters can be made to work (with the code as is, I end up with an array in the first element of @stuff).

Comment: @ikegami just tried `return @monsters` with Rakudo™ v2022.07, and I get a strange `[[ ... ]]` array-within-an-array result. Joseph, is that what you mean by "I end up with an array in the first element of @stuff"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Perl5::Inline` puts return values into scalar context.

As background, in Perl 5, context flows inwards into routines, so a routine always knows which context it's in.

In Perl 6, context flows outwards, so a routine returns an object that can behave differently in different context.

This impedance mismatch between Perl 5 and Perl 6 means that `Inline::Perl5` has to decide to call Perl 5 routines in one context, and that's scalar.

As ikegami pointed out, the proper solution is to return a proper scalar, aka reference (in Perl 5 speak). Limitations in `Inline::Perl5` might mean you need to explicitly dereference on the Perl 6 side.

Comment: Yes raiph is right, the story is a little more complicated than
this:

   use Inline::Perl5;
   my $p5 = Inline::Perl5.new;

   my $perl5_defsub = q:to/END/;
      sub whadaya_want {
          wantarray() ? 'LIST' : 'SCALAR';
      }
   END

   $p5.run: $perl5_defsub;

   my $run_context  = $p5.run(  'whadaya_want' );
   my $call_context = $p5.call( 'whadaya_want' );  
   
   say "run: ", $run_context;
   say "call: ", $call_context;
   # run: SCALAR
   # call: LIST

Comment: Okay, one more time:

Comment: Yes raiph is right, the story is a little more complicated than
this:

   `use Inline::Perl5;
   my $p5 = Inline::Perl5.new;

   my $perl5_defsub = q:to/END/;
      sub whadaya_want {
          wantarray() ? 'LIST' : 'SCALAR';
      }
   END

   $p5.run: $perl5_defsub;

   my $run_context  = $p5.run(  'whadaya_want' );
   my $call_context = $p5.call( 'whadaya_want' );  
   
   say "run: ", $run_context;
   say "call: ", $call_context;
   # run: SCALAR
   # call: LIST`

Comment: You know, I find it peculiar that some people don't get why not everyone likes stackoverflow.   I'll do another update of my question to get in my code in a readable fashion.

Answer (score 11):

Moritz's answer is excellent and explains IP5's dilemma. But niner is ingenious, so IP5 provides all the variations one needs:

---

- Call a Perl ***sub*** in ***list*** context:

  ```
  Inline::Perl5.new.call: 'subname', arg1, arg2 ...
  ```

  See [IP5: Call a Perl function](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5#call-a-perl-5-function).

---

- Call a Perl ***sub*** in ***scalar*** context:

  ```
  Inline::Perl5.new.run: 'subname arg1, arg2 ...'
  ```

  or

  ```
  EVAL 'subname arg1, arg2 ...', :lang<Perl5>
  ```

  See [IP5: Run arbitrary Perl code](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5#run-arbitrary-perl-5-code).

---

- Call a Perl ***method*** in ***list*** context:

  Use regular Raku syntax:

  ```
  $perl-object .foo: arg1, arg2 ...
  ```

  to call the `foo` method on a Perl object held in `$perl-object` passing it `arg1` and `arg2` as its first two arguments (ignoring the invocant).

  See [IP5: Invoke a method on a Perl object](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5#invoke-a-method-on-a-perl-5-object).

---

- Call a Perl ***method*** in ***scalar*** context:

  Use regular Raku syntax but insert `Scalar` as the first positional argument (ignoring the invocant):

  ```
  $perl-object .foo: Scalar, arg1, arg2 ...
  ```

  to call the `foo` method on a Perl object held in `$perl-object` passing it `arg1` and `arg2` as its first two arguments.

  IP5 removes the `Scalar` before calling the Perl method.

  See [IP5: Invoking a method in scalar context](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5#invoking-a-method-in-scalar-context).

---

## Dealing with the Inlines

I think Moritz's answer was a solid resolution of the question, and that mine has rounded it out.

But what if you're reading this and are interested in, or dealing with, other Inline issues?

The sections starting at **What to expect when using foreign language adaptors** of [my answer to **Raku: getting array ref for Perl Module**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768361/1077672) are an attempt to outline a mini generic guide on what to expect, and how to deal with problems, relative to Raku's Inlines.

Comment: I recommend waiting a day or so before posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: I appreciate the Perl5 knowledge in this SO Question, and in the 2 (remaining?) answers. But any commentary regarding "answering one's own question" appears moot at this point in time.

Comment: @jubilatious1 Thanks. My bit about answering one's own question was moot when I wrote it too. What I meant was... Nevermind. :) Answer edited.