# How on Raku do we fill out multi variables individually from corresponding regex captures

Tags: raku

How is the simplest Raku to fill out so many individual variables  from a result regex captures in corresponding order
( just like Perl  `my ($a, $b $c, $d, $e)= 'hello' =~ m{ ^(h) (e) (l) (l) (o) }x`

) ?

try such:

```
> my ($a, $b, $c, $arr);
[<$a $b $c>]= 'hello world' ~~ m{ (h)(e)(l)lo };
say "\n=$a\n=$b\n=$c"

Use of uninitialized value element of type Any in string context.
    Methods .^name, .raku, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
      in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

...

fails.
Please show the correct and nearest similar way to Perl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
 my ($a, $b, $c) =   'hello' =~ m{ ^(h) (e) (l) (l) (o) }x ; # Perl
 my ($a, $b, $c) = |('hello' ~~ m{ ^(h) (e) (l) (l) (o) }) ; # Raku
```

## The differences between my Perl and Raku code

---

**Added `|( ... )`**

In Perl, matching operations generally return either one string, or a list of strings.

It's similar in Raku, except [`Match`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Match) objects are returned instead of strings, and often only one is returned in scenarios in which a Perl dev might expect a list of them. Your scenario is an example.

(This additional complexity is a trade off to make the additional power and utility of general parsing easily, naturally, and automatically available. For more discussion of this see eg [Extracting from `.bib` file with Raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172113/extracting-from-bib-file-with-raku-previously-aka-perl-6).)

Fortunately, if you treat a `Match` object as a string, it automatically coerces to a string. Similarly, if you treat a `Match` object as a list, then it'll automatically coerce to a list.

(This is a general theme in Raku; if you treat an object of one kind of type as if it were another kind of type, and on balance it makes sense for it to always automatically coerce given the two kinds of types involved, then it does so.)

If an object type is ostensibly "singular" but also naturally has a "plural" aspect (eg it serves as a "parent" of "children"), then it may support automatic coercion to a plural thing if you treat it as a plural thing. For example, an operation such as `.list` may work as a way to list *numbered* children (and `.hash` to list *named* children).

Another approach among many that will work if a given "singular" kind of class/object supports it is subscripting:

```
say ('foo' ~~ m{ (.) (.) })[*];                          # (｢f｣ ｢o｣)
say ('foo' ~~ m{ (.) (.) $<I'm-named>=(.) })<I'm-named>; # ｢o｣
```

For my 2023 update of this answer I've used JJ's suggestion of `|(...)`.

---

**`~~` instead of `~=`**

Raku's `~~` is a general purpose "smart match" operator that can take many types of data on its left and right hand sides. One of its roles is to replace Perl's regex match operator `~=`.

---

**`{ ... }` instead of `{ ... }x`**

In Perl, top level white space in a regex is part of the pattern unless you append an `x` adverb/option. Not so in Raku.

## About the error message you got

```
[<$a $b $c>]= 'hello world' ~~ m{ (h)(e)(l)lo };
```

The assignment in `[<$a $b $c>]= ...` didn't work in the way I presume you were thinking it would.

First and foremost, the `<...>`, which is similar to Perl's "quote words" (`qw`) feature, treats `$foo` as the *literal string* `'$foo'`. So:

- `<$a $b $c>` is equivalent to `('$a', '$b', '$c')`.
- `[<$a $b $c>]` is equivalent to `['$a', '$b', '$c']`.

Because of this, while the assignment *does* assign its results into the array, it does so by *overwriting* the anonymous `Scalar` container *elements* of the array that contain the *strings* `'$a'`, `'$b'`, etc, rather than *updating* the *variables* you declared (`$a` etc) which you were thinking had been bound to the corresponding elements of the array by your code.

This leads to the error message, which is repeated 3 times, once each for `$a`, `$b`, and `$c`.

Comment: ... And Match objects are Captures, i.e., lists and associative at the same time. Coercing to list or anything that puts it in a list context will do.

Answer (score 6):

You'll never do wrong following Raiph's answers. But I'm going to try and explain a bit why that works, and propose alternatives. A [`Match` is a `Capture`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Match), a beast that's essentially a list and an associative array at the same time. What you want is to have the result as a list, same as it happens in Perl. How do you extract the "list" part (or coerce it to a list)? Easy: use explicit coercion (as Raiph suggests) or try and put it in a [list *context*](https://docs.raku.org/language/list#List_contexts). What creates a list context? [Flattening](https://docs.raku.org/language/list#Flattening_) does:

```
my ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) = |('hello' ~~ m{ ^(h) (e) (l) (l) (o) });
```

List binding does too:

```
my ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) := 'hello' ~~ m{ ^(h) (e) (l) (l) (o) };
```

The thing is that every one of the variables will still contain a Match; what you probably want is the self same thing as in Perl, a list of strings. We can get that with this combo:

```
my @array is Array[Str(Match)] = | ('hello' ~~ m{ ^(h) (e) (l) (l) (o) });
```

Where we get the list context in the right hand side, and by explicitly declaring an array with [coercing elements](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-Coercion_type), we get `[h e l l o]` as a result.

Comment: Time to add an entry in the `docs` for that, JJ? The `beast` Class? ;-)

Comment: ```~<<('hello' ~~ m{ ^(h) (e) (l) (l) (o) })``` uses the hyper ```<<``` to distribute the ```~``` .Str coercer over the Match ;)